# OSX equivalent of piping sound to linux's aplay

Tags: macos, audio

On Ubuntu I am able to use `aplay` to play sound generated live from a script by piping the output of my script to aplay's stdin :

```
./generate_sound.py | aplay -r 2000 -c2 -f MU_LAW
cat sample.wav | aplay
```

Is there a way to do the same from terminal in OSX? I think `afplay` doesn't support this ...

Maybe someone knows another OSX command line sound player that would do the trick?

Comment: How is `sample.wav | aplay` even a valid command?

Comment: yes forgot the `cat`. Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had high hopes for redirection/piping, but `afplay /dev/stdin <<< $(generate_sound.py)` failed for all the formats I tried. Sadly `afplay` doesn't let you specify the format, and so it tries instead to sniff it which probably involves seeking which doesn't work with pipes.

I think you'd better find another command line player. [sox](https://blogs.fsfe.org/marklindhout/2013/02/need-to-play-high-fidelity-white-noise-listen-to-devurandom-on-osx/) seems like a good candidate. And! It's installable via homebrew: `brew install sox` and you can pipe data to it like so:

`cat whatever.raw | play -t raw -e floating-point -b 32 -c 2 -r 44100  -`

Comment: I found mpv to work well - `nc (address) | mpv -` in my case.

Comment: `sox` play command doesn't seem to take data from stdin

Comment: @monokrome sure it does, check the updated answer

Comment: Hmm... I guess it needed more flags and that's why `-` didn't work for me yesterday! Albeit, I still don't get audio output - at least it *thinks* it's working now. lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To Listen to an FM station on a mac

```
rtl_fm -f 95.3e6 -M wbfm -s 200000 -r 48000 – | aplay -r 48k -f S16_LE
```

To record for 10s

```
export AUDIOSAMPLERATE=48000
export SAMPLERATE=200000
export FREQ="127.2m"

rtl_fm -f $FREQ -M am -s $SAMPLERATE -r $AUDIOSAMPLERATE | sox -r $AUDIOSAMPLERATE -t raw -e s -b 16 -c 1 -V1 - FILENAME.wav&
sleep 10
killall rtl_fm
```

Comment: The question is "Is there a way to do the same from terminal in OSX? I think afplay doesn't support this" but your answer on how to play is specific to aplay, which is a Ubuntu tool >.<

Answer (score 0):

`./generate_sound.py | afplay /dev/stdin` and other forms don't sem to work, sadly.

However, this works:
`afplay /dev/stdin < audio.mp3`

So, a workaround would be to generate a temp file and then play it.

Comment: This because on macos pipes created with `<` are seekable, pipes created with `|` are not.
You can test this behavior with a simple program like: https://pastebin.com/uxQg4bLL